# How to connect Django and .net core project as a single application?

Tags: python, c#, asp.net, django, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to connect Django project and .NET core project because I want it take advantage of good library available in python so I will make one strong .NET core project.so through some lite on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there is no way to run both `Django/Python` and `.Net/C#` in a same process. But there are at least one other option.

The options is using `MicroService` architecture. That means you create two separate projects, one for `.Net` and another for `Django/Python`. Then make these two projects talk to each other.

They can communicate with each other in several ways. Most common way is to communicate via `REST`. It means each project provide the other side a bunch of APIs. The other side can consume (call) the API to receive or send the required data.

Another way to communicate is to use a shared database. Another one is use messaging solutions like `RabbitMQ`.

In `MicroService` architecture, you can host each one on a convenient web server or, if you enjoy fancy technologies, you can use `docker`.

**Update**

A practical example would be like this:

1. Your Python side has the functionality of calculating direct distance between point A and B.
2. You create a Django app with a REST API called `calc`
3. It get A and B as via query string. Just like `http://localhost:5000/api/calc?lata=53.123&longa=34.134&latb=53.999&longb=34.999` (consider a and b in query parameters)
4. Create a .Net app wither as web or desktop
5. With the .Net app, call `calc` api via utilities like `HttpClient`
6. Now, you have the results in your .Net part

Comment: I understand what you are saying and thank you for replying me. now I decide I go with REST but can you give example how to communicate to each other.so I can understand more in this topic . or give some source link so  I can go depth on this topic.

Comment: Hi yash, did you find out how to do this? I’m looking for something similar and this thread is the only resource I have found :/